# Can you use Cordova in an offline intranet environment?

Tags: node.js, cordova, installation, offline

In the government organisation I work for we have many workstations on a closed intranet network. There's a way to get internet but that doesn't work for every application.

I'm doing a bit of research to Cordova and Phonegap, and I'd like to know if it's possible install Cordova and compile projects with it, all while fully offline.

I can install Node.js, the JDK, the Android SDK and ANT fully offline. However, the installation command for Cordova is 'npm install -g cordova'.

Is there a workaround for this? I know there's a [source zip](http://cordova.apache.org/#download) file download but I simply don't know where to put all those files.

Also, upon building a project with Cordova I can see it checking for latest versions of plugins on github. I think it's possible to download the plugins offline. But would the build process succeed if the plugins version checks fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [npmbox](https://github.com/arei/npmbox), it is the new name of npmzip which will allow you to install offline npm packages by one file