# Is there an alternative for npmzip?

Tags: node.js, zip, installation, npm

As mentioned by @NS Gopikrishnan in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295050/how-to-install-npm-g-on-offline-server) there was an npmzip tool that we could use to create npm install packages that include all dependancies for that package.

Unfortunately npmzip is no [longer available](http://registry.npmjs.org/npmzip/-/npmzip-0.1.3.tgz).

I would be very interested in creating offline install packages that include all dependancies. Does anyone know of an alternative to npmzip that does this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @kamil's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389535/can-you-use-cordova-in-an-offline-intranet-environment) there's indeed an alternative to npmzip. It is called [npmbox](https://github.com/arei/npmbox)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. In online environment, `npm install --no-bin-link`. You will have a **entire flattened** `node_modules`
> 2. Then, bundle this **flawless** `node_modules` with `tar / zip / rar / 7z` etc
> 3. In offline environment, extract the bundle, that's it

P.S [node-pac](https://github.com/mikefrey/node-pac) is another option, but it can't deal with the packages which still need downloading something for installation.